# Does std::initializer_list have a copy constructor and is it ever used?

Tags: c++, c++14, copy-constructor, initializer-list

does std::initializer_list have a copy constructor and if it does, does it ever get used and in which cases? because I noticed the following doesn't compile in GCC:

```cpp
std::initializer_list<int>{{1,2,3,4}};
```

while the one below does

```cpp
class Test{
    public:
        Test(const std::initializer_list<int> &){}
};
Test{{1,2,3,4,5,6}};
```

So I suspect if std::initializer_list< int > had the constructor that Test class has, the first piece of code would compile

Answer (score 6):

> So I suspect if std::initializer_list< int > had the constructor that Test class has, the first piece of code would compile

That would assume that "uniform initialization" is actually *uniform*, which is always a dangerous assumption to make.

`initializer_list` has special rules about being constructed from a braced-init-list. If you apply a braced-init-list to an `initializer_list<T>`, then [[dcl.init.list]/3.5](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.init.list#3.5) kicks in, which says go "below," skipping the remaining subparagraphs. [And "below" says](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.init.list#5):

> An object of type `std​::​initializer_­list<E>` is constructed from an initializer list as if the implementation generated and materialized a prvalue of type “array of `N` `const E`”, where `N` is the number of elements in the initializer list.

Well, you're constructing your `initializer_list<int>` from a *single element*, which itself is a braced-init-list. That braced-init-list now gets applied to `E`, which is `int`. And because that list has more than one entry, that doesn't work.

Because subparagraph 3.5 *explicitly* skipped all of the other subparagraphs in that section, it *doesn't matter* if that inner braced-init-list could create an `initializer_list<int>`. The compiler never checks for that, because the check to do that [was in 3.6](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.init.list#3.6), which was skipped.

---

For the record, `initializer_list` does have (defaulted) copy/move constructors and assignment operators.

Comment: So std::initializer_list<int> list = {1,2,3,4,5}; uses copy constructor of list to initialize it?

Comment: @Pooria: No; it uses "copy-list-initialization", which is a form of list-initialization, and that doesn't need to invoke a copy constructor.

Answer (score 1):

According to [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list/initializer_list), the only constructor available is the default constructor.

This might have to do with how it is usually implemented : a standard C-style array.
For additional information, I will suggest [this video from Jason Turner at CppCon2018](https://youtu.be/uQyT-5iWUow?t=1687) that provides insight on lifetime.

You can however, initialize a container with an `initializer_list` effectively treating it as its "copy".

Comment: Wouldn't be there an implicitly generated copy constructor thou? I mean if it's not explicitly deleted there's supposed to be an implicit one.

Comment: I'm fairly certain that cppreference exhaustively lists each available constructor. However, [according to this minimal example](https://repl.it/@Voltra1/Initializer-List-Construction) you can "copy" in the same scope, but as soon as you leave the scope you will have issues (e.g. returning from a function).

Comment: actually that example just copies the initializer_list object not the underlying memory, and the tmp function is perfectly compileable too, thou when you get out of scope of tmp the underlying memory is freed, btw what's currently in there doesn't get compiled on GCC. After all if cppreference lists all constructors I think it's safe to assume it has no copy constructors then

Comment: It does compile but issues warnings (out of scope reference)

Comment: Using GCC 8.3.0 it doesn't what version are you tryin it on?

Comment: Using clang 7.0.0-3 : "warning: returning address of local temporary object"

Comment: Well I said using GCC not Clang lol;   
error: could not convert '{a}' from '<brace-enclosed initializer list>' to 'std::initializer_list<int>'
   std::initializer_list<int> b{a};

Comment: According to this [compiler explorer setup](https://godbolt.org/z/DhuqrZ) it compiles fine with GCC even with targeted flags. GCC has always been known to be more "permissive" than most other compilers in regards to C/C++.

Comment: you're not using original code, it's b{a} not b = a in the original, which again doesn't get compiled in GCC, but compiles in Clang

Comment: Indeed, for some reason it cannot resolve the constructor although it can when using the "alternative" (`=`) syntax.

Comment: which constructor you mean? copy constructor you mean?

Comment: Indeed (or similar)

Comment: Well lol indeed we just had reached the conclusion that it doesn't have one!

Comment: Interestingly enough, if you use `b(a)` instead of the uniform initializing syntax it compiles. With optimization level 3 you can notice it seems to work fine as well.

Comment: To me it seems like it's clunky gcc back at it again.

Comment: No, we do not exhaustively list the implicitly declared constructors. At least not consistently. We probably should.

Comment: @pooria There is no implicity generated copy constructor, because other constructors (e.g. default constructor) are explicitly declared.